# Adding sendgrid:starter failed ! Error Provisioning User - Error creating customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I just finished installing the Devise gem without any problems and now I am trying to install the Sendgrid add-on from the command line using:

```
heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter
```

I have done this before with other apps without any problems.  However with this time I am getting this error:

```
Adding sendgrid:starter on languagecheck... failed
 !    Error Provisioning User - Error creating customer
```

I have gone through my code several times.  I tried logging out and back into Heroku without any problems.  I tried searching for someone with a similar error, with no luck.

I cannot find any other error messages elsewhere.  Does anyone have an idea for why this is happening?  Could it have something to do with Sendgrid's server being down? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I checked with Sendgrid and Heroku and their servers are not down...

Comment: There was an AWS networking issue around this time; I'd try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Heroku about this issue.  They responded with "Sorry for the trouble there. I'm seeing the same error returned for other customers attempting to provision the Sendgrid add-on; looping them in to find out more." I haven't heard back from them yet as to what the reason behind it was, but I'll post it if I ever find out.

Comment: This isn't the proper answer. Would you please update it with what worked for you?